# Quotient map matrix representation (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $G = \text{span}\{(1,-1,0,0)\}$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and let $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the linear defined by
> $$f(x, y, z, t) := (x + y, z + t).$$ Find a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4/G$ and calculate the matrix of the linear map $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4/G \to \mathbb{R}^2$ in this basis and in the usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It is well known that, if $G \subset \text{ker}(f)$ (and this is the case), then the linear map $\phi$ is well defined. We can take as basis of $\mathbb{R}^4/ G$
$$\{(0,0,1,0) + G, (0,0,0,1) + G, (1,0,1,0) + G\}.$$

However, I got no idea how to construct the matrix of $\phi$ from it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well label these $v_1,v_2, v_3$ and then $\phi v_1=(0,1)$, $\phi v_2=(0,1)$, $\phi v_3=(1,1)=1\cdot(1,0)+1\cdot(0,1)$ and so ......

Comment: So the matrix will be \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}?

Comment: If that's your convention for matrices, yes. (It's what I'd use but some people are left-handed)